# Why is it OK to assign a std::string& to a std::string variable in C++?

Tags: c++

```
class MyClass:
public:
   MyClass(const std::string& my_str);
private:
  std::string _myStr
```

In the implementation:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& my_str):
   _mystr(my_str)
```

How can you assign a reference (my_str is `const std::string&`) to a non-reference variable (_mystr, which is `std::string`)?

In my mental model, a variable is a block of space in memory can be filled with stuff that is the same type as the variable's declared type. So a `std::string` variable is a block of space that can hold a string (eg: "abcd"), while a `const std::string&` is a block of space in memory that can hold a "reference" (kind of vague what it is, unlike a pointer which is an address to another block in memory). When you assign one variable to another, you are copying the content stored in one memory block into another. So how can you copy a *std::string&* into a *std::string* - their types are different.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: The assignment operator and copy constructor both take a const reference as an input - you are just copying whatever string `my_str` references into the class variable `_myStr`

Comment: @TylerV in c++: ```a = b``` means "take the content in b's memory block and copy them into the memory block for a". If a is std::string, and b is std::string&, how will the above operation work legally? Is there something else going on under the hood?

Comment: No, in c++ `a = b` means call `a.operator=(b)` and do whatever it implements (see [operator= reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)). Also read about [copy constructor details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). When you assign an object or copy/initialize it from another object these are the methods it uses.

Comment: The whole point of a reference is that it _is_ the thing. Your mental model of a reference is more appropriate for a pointer.

Comment: `MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& my_str): _mystr(my_str)` is functionally similar to `MyClass::MyClass(const std::string * my_str): _mystr(*my_str)`, except that the latter/pass-by-pointer form is a bit less convenient for calling code to use, and introduces the possibility of the constructor being called with a NULL pointer.

Comment: With very few exceptions when using the name of a reference in C++ it behaves exactly as if you had named the object that the reference references instead. That is the point of a reference and makes it very different from a pointer. You cannot actually copy the reference itself. There is no way to refer to the reference itself in an expression. You always refer to the referenced object.

Comment: A reference, practically, is just an alternative name for an object.   So, `a = b` where `b` is a reference to an object `c` assigns `a` so it has the same value as `c`.   For a `std::string` which has an `operator=()`,  `a = b` is the same as `a.operator=(b)` and, if `b` is a reference to an actual object `c`, that has the same effect `a.operator=(c)`.      So your reasoning about references is incorrect (your thinking has a pointer more like a pointer than is actually the case in C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you do not make an assignment, actually.

This line:

```
_mystr(my_str)
```

Is invoking the **copy constructor** of your `_mystr` member.

The copy constructor received a `const std::string&` (`my_str`, in your case), and constructs a clone of the object it refers to into your member `_mystr`.

But to answer your question in a more general way:

It is possible to assign a variable of type reference into a non-reference type. What will happen is the **assignment operator** of the target will be invoked. The assignment operator (of `std::string`, in this case) accepts (like the copy constructor) a `const std::string&`, and assigns a clone of the object it refers to into your member `_mystr`.

Therefore, this will work as well:

```
void f(std::string const & str)
{
   std::string local_str = str;
   // ...
}
```

All the above is correct in general for all classes.

Non-class types behave in a similar manner, e.g.:

```
int i1;
int & ri1 = i1;
int i2 = ri1;  // Will assign a copy of the value referenced by ri1, i.e. the value of i1, into i2
```

See more here about [Initialisation and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350155/).

And [Why are initialization lists preferred over assignments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794983/).

Comment: thanks. is ```_mystr(my_str)``` the same as doing ```mystr = my_str``` ? Why do class constructor prefer the first over the 2nd version ?

Comment: No it is not. The first is using copy ctor, the 2nd assignment. The only special case is something like: `std::string s = another_s;` - although it looks like assignment it will actually be an initialization using the ctor. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350155/initialisation-and-assignment.

Comment: So in my example, can I do _mystr = my_str instead of _mystr(my_str) in the constructor function of MyClass? Do both have the same effect ?

Comment: No. then it will be an assignment. The only case where assignment is "replaced" by construction is when you define a variable and assign it immediatly, e.g. `A a = another_a;`. In your case the variable is a member and defined in the class itself, so this does not apply. See the link I added in my last comment.

Comment: Is the 2nd version (_mystr = my_str) illegal in C++ for the constructor ?

Comment: You can write it in the body of you `MyClass` constructor. It is valid. But it will invoke a different method (assignment instead of ctor). Usually it's rcomended to use the 1st way (copy ctor).

Comment: in the example, _mystr is initialized in the header but had never been assigned. So it seems doing _mystr = my_str is the more appropriate thing to do in the constructor for the class? ie, "assign the value referenced by my_str into _mystr". But why do people do _mystr(my_str) more commonly in such constructors ?

Comment: Even if you gave _mystr a default value in your class header, I would still use `_mystr(my_str)`. It's a small difference, but using ctor might be a bit more efficient than assignment. Also since you are in the ctor of `MyClass` is seems straightforward to use ctors to intialize the members. See here why is it prefered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794983/why-are-initialization-lists-preferred-over-assignments.

Answer (score 3):

`my_str` is a *name* for another `string`. The "mental model" you are using is that of a pointer to another string,  but a reference is not a pointer.

What's your mental model for this code?

```
std::string s1, s2;
s1 = s2;
```

Use that same model for the code in the question;  `my_str` names a `std::string` somewhere in memory, just as `s2` does.

---

Also note that assignment of class types means to *call an assignment operator function*,  which is not the same as copying content of a memory block.  One of the ideas of object-oriented programming is that assigning from one object to another brings the objects to have the same logical meaning,  not the same memory content.

For example, `string` is often structured as a small memory block with an internal pointer to a large dynamically allocated block.  Two different `string` objects will each have allocated their own blocks, even if assigned to have the same content stored in that block for now.  You certainly wouldn't want to implement `s1 = s2;` by copying the memory block of `s2` to `s1`. Instead you want to copy between the managed allocations of each string (and resize s1's allocation if needed).

---

One more thing: the code in your question is doing *construction* and not *assignment*. Those are different things, as assignment must update a valid state that already exists.

But these same considerations apply to both cases.

Answer (score 0):

`_mystr(my_str)` is invoking the copy constructor of `std::basic_string` to initialize `_mystr` with a string identical (in characters) to the string in `my_str`; see (7) in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string.